# Return Unique Element with a Tolerance

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, there is this [`unique` command](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) that returns thew unique rows in an array. This is a very handy command.

But the problem is that I can't assign tolerance to it-- in double precision, we always have to compare two elements within a precision. Is there a built-in command that returns unique elements, within a certain tolerance?

Comment: Taking your problem a step further maybe you are interested in clustering?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**As of R2015a**, there is finally a function to do this, [`uniquetol`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uniquetol.html) (**before R2015a**, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20850949/2778484)):

> `uniquetol`  Set unique within a tolerance.
>       `uniquetol` is similar to `unique`. Whereas `unique` performs exact comparisons, `uniquetol` performs comparisons using a tolerance.

The syntax is straightforward:

> `C = uniquetol(A,TOL)` returns the unique values in `A` using tolerance `TOL`.

As are the semantics:

> Each value of `C` is within tolerance of one value of `A`, but no two elements in `C` are within tolerance of each other. `C` is sorted in ascending order. Two values `u` and `v` are within tolerance if:
>       `abs(u-v) <= TOL*max(A(:),[],1)`

It can also operate "`ByRows`", and the tolerance can be scaled by an input "`DataScale`" rather than by the maximum value in the input data.

But there is an important note about uniqueness of the solutions:

> There can be multiple valid `C` outputs that satisfy the condition, "no two elements in `C` are within tolerance of each other." For example, swapping columns in `A` can result in a different solution being returned, because the input is sorted lexicographically by the columns. Another result is that `uniquetol(-A,TOL)` may not give the same results as `-uniquetol(A,TOL)`.

There is also a new function `ismembertol` is related to `ismember` in the same way as above.

Answer (score 13):

With R2015a, this question finally has a simple answer (see [my other answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27428109/2778484) for details).  For releases prior to R2015a, there is such a built-in (undocumented) function: `_mergesimpts`. A safe guess at the composition of the name is "merge similar points".

The function is called with the following syntax:

```
xMerged = builtin('_mergesimpts',x,tol,[type])
```

The data array `x` is `N-by-D`, where `N` is the number of points, and `D` is the number of dimensions. The tolerances for each dimension are specified by a `D`-element row vector, `tol`. The optional input argument `type` is a string (`'first'` (default) or `'average'`) indicating how to merge similar elements.

The output `xMerged` will be `M-by-D`, where `M<=N`. *It is sorted*.

**Examples, 1D data**:

```
>> x = [1; 1.1; 1.05];             % elements need not be sorted
>> builtin('_mergesimpts',x,eps)   % but the output is sorted
ans =
    1.0000
    1.0500
    1.1000
```

Merge types:

```
>> builtin('_mergesimpts',x,0.1,'first')
ans =
    1.0000  % first of [1, 1.05] since abs(1 - 1.05) < 0.1
    1.1000
>> builtin('_mergesimpts',x,0.1,'average')
ans =
    1.0250  % average of [1, 1.05]
    1.1000
>> builtin('_mergesimpts',x,0.2,'average')
ans =
    1.0500  % average of [1, 1.1, 1.05]
```

**Examples, 2D data**:

```
>> x = [1 2; 1.06 2; 1.1 2; 1.1 2.03]
x =
    1.0000    2.0000
    1.0600    2.0000
    1.1000    2.0000
    1.1000    2.0300
```

All 2D points unique to machine precision:

```
>> xMerged = builtin('_mergesimpts',x,[eps eps],'first')
xMerged =
    1.0000    2.0000
    1.0600    2.0000
    1.1000    2.0000
    1.1000    2.0300
```

Merge based on second dimension tolerance:

```
>> xMerged = builtin('_mergesimpts',x,[eps 0.1],'first')
xMerged =
    1.0000    2.0000
    1.0600    2.0000
    1.1000    2.0000   % first of rows 3 and 4
>> xMerged = builtin('_mergesimpts',x,[eps 0.1],'average')
xMerged =
    1.0000    2.0000
    1.0600    2.0000
    1.1000    2.0150   % average of rows 3 and 4
```

Merge based on first dimension tolerance:

```
>> xMerged = builtin('_mergesimpts',x,[0.2 eps],'average')
xMerged =
    1.0533    2.0000   % average of rows 1 to 3
    1.1000    2.0300
>> xMerged = builtin('_mergesimpts',x,[0.05 eps],'average')
xMerged =
    1.0000    2.0000
    1.0800    2.0000   % average of rows 2 and 3
    1.1000    2.0300   % row 4 not merged because of second dimension
```

Merge based on both dimensions:

```
>> xMerged = builtin('_mergesimpts',x,[0.05 .1],'average')
xMerged =
    1.0000    2.0000
    1.0867    2.0100   % average of rows 2 to 4
```

Comment: +1 Nice! I came across this function myself, and a quick search led me to your explanation. This could come in handy.

Comment: @Amro I found it while trying to figure out how `griddata` identifies "duplicate" points.  It's too bad there's not proper documentation for this functionality.  Please feel free to edit this post to correct my mistakes.  I recall there being some inaccuracies or at lease some missing details, but never had the time to get to drill down and get it 100% right.

Comment: I think you covered it all.. The only detail I can add is that the function accepts only non-complex non-sparse double-precision data points.

Comment: @chappjc is there a way to get the code of _mergesimpts ? I made a matlab function that utilises _mergesimpts. BUT the matlab code-generator application cannot work with builtin functions. Is there a way to get the matlab code of _mergesimpts?

Comment: @Abhinav Nope. Sorry.

Comment: @chappjc thanks for the quick response. Can you also tell me the reason as to why this isn't possible?

Comment: @Abhinav MATLAB Coder only has limited support, for a subset of functions in MATLAB.  It's up to MathWorks what functions they decide to add code generation for.  However, there is probably code generation for `meshgrid` and `ndgrid` which use this function so you can perhaps figure out how to make those functions give what you need.  You could post a new specific question if you think you've tried everything.

Comment: @Amro Ugh, I decided to rollback until release.  Don't want to violate the NDA, assuming they actually care.  Hopefully no one else who doesn't care posts it...

Comment: @chappjc: no worries, I won't tell :) I've also jumped the gun in the past about a new feature (I think in a comment on Yair Altman's blog), but he kindly reminded me of the NDA thing!

Comment: @Amro Haha, he just did the same for me regarding [`mxCreateUninit*`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27413169/2778484)!  I just couldn't help myself.

Comment: @chappjc: another nice addition. I really should download 15a, and check it out myself..

Answer (score 11):

This is a difficult problem. I'd even claim it to be impossible to solve in general, because of what I'd call the transitivity problem. Suppose that we have three elements in a set, {A,B,C}. I'll define a simple function isSimilarTo, such that isSimilarTo(A,B) will return a true result if the two inputs are within a specified tolerance of each other. (Note that everything I will say here is meaningful in one dimension as well as in multiple dimensions.) So if two numbers are known to be "similar" to each other, then we will choose to group them together.

So suppose we have values {A,B,C} such that isSimilarTo(A,B) is true, and that isSimilarTo(B,C) is also true. Should we decide to group all three together, even though isSimilarTo(A,C) is false?

Worse, move to two dimensions. Start with k points equally spaced around the perimeter of a circle. Assume the tolerance is chosen such that any point is within the specified tolerance of its immediate neighbors, but not to any other point. How would you choose to resolve which points are "unique" in the setting?

I'll claim that this problem of intransitivity makes the grouping problem not possible to resolve, at least not perfectly, and certainly not in any efficient manner. Perhaps one might try an approach based on a k-means style of aggregation. But this will be quite inefficient, as well, such an approach generally needs to know in advance the number of groups to look for.

Having said that, I would still offer a compromise, something that can sometimes work within limits. The trick is found in [Consolidator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8354), as found on the Matlab Central file exchange. My approach was to effectively round the inputs to within the specified tolerance. Having done that, a combination of unique and accumarray allows the aggregation to be done efficiently, even for large sets of data in one or many dimensions.

This is a reasonable approach when the tolerance is large enough that when multiple pieces of data belong together, they will be rounded to the same value, with occasional errors made by the rounding step.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such function that I know of. One tricky aspect is that if your tolerance is, say, 1e-10, and you have a vector with values that are equally spaced at 9e-11, the first and the third entry are not the same, but the first is the same as the second, and the second is the same as the third - so how many "uniques" are there?

One way to solve the problem is that you round your values to a desired precision, and then run unique on that. You can do that using round2 (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4261-round2), or using the following simple way:

```
r = rand(100,1); % some random data
roundedData = round(r*1e6)/1e6; % round to 1e-6
uniqueValues = unique(roundedData);
```

You could also do it  using the hist command, as long as the precision is not too high:

```
r = rand(100,1); % create 100 random values between 0 and 1
grid = 0:0.001:1; % creates a vector of uniquely spaced values 
counts = hist(r,grid); % now you know for each element in 'grid' how many values there are
uniqueValues = grid(counts>0); % and these are the uniques
```

Answer (score 4):

I've come across this problem before.  The trick is to first sort the data and then use the diff function to find the difference between each item.  Then compare when that difference is less then your tolerance.
This is the code that I use:

```
tol = 0.001
[Y I] = sort(items(:));
uni_mask = diff([0; Y]) > tol;
%if you just want the unique items:
uni_items = Y(uni_mask); %in sorted order
uni_items = items(I(uni_mask));  % in the original order
```

This doesn't take care of "drifting" ... so something like 0:0.00001:100 would actually return one unique value.

If you want something that can handle "drifting" then I would use histc but you need to make some sort of rough guess as to how many items you're willing to have.

```
NUM = round(numel(items) / 10); % a rough guess
bins = linspace(min(items), max(items), NUM);
counts = histc(items, bins);
unit_items = bins(counts > 0);
```

BTW: I wrote this in a text-editor away from matlab so there may be some stupid typos or off by one errors.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to define well, assume you have a tolerance of 1.
Then what would be the outcome of `[1; 2; 3; 4]`?

When you have multiple columns a definition could become even more challenging.

However, if you are mostly worried about rounding issues, you can solve most of it by one of these two approaches:

1. Round all numbers (considering your tolerance), and then use `unique`
2. Start with the top row as your unique set, use [`ismemberf`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23294-ismemberf) to determine whether each new row is unique and if so, add it to your unique set.

The first approach has the weakness that 0.499999999 and 0.500000000 may not be seen as duplicates. Whilst the second approach has the weakness that the order of your input matters.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck the other day with a **MatLab 2010**, so, no round(X,n), no _mergesimpts (At least I couldn't get it to work) so, a simple solution that works (at least for my data):

Using `rat` default tolerance:

```
unique(cellstr(rat(x)))
```

Other tolerance:

```
unique(cellstr(rat(x,tol)))
```