# Linux (GLNXA64) using mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix R2013b

Tags: c, linux, matlab, mex, undocumented-behavior

In one MEX file, I created an output matrix with the command (working fine):

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix((mwSize)destLen, 1, mxUINT8_CLASS, mxREAL);
```

For speedup I wanted to use the dynamic memory uninitialized, which lead me to the *undocumented* command:

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix((mwSize)destLen, 1, mxUINT8_CLASS, mxREAL);
```

working also very fine within Win32 and Win64.

Using exactly the same code within my Linux environment leads to the following warning from compiler:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

and the code crashes, which show, that the returned integer value is not that one pointing to the correct memory address.

What can I do to use `mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix`?

Comment: Oh, I got some further `bad news`: Just played around with MATLAB R2014a Pre: in libmx.dll and libmex.dll I'm missing many former _undocumented_ functions. Seems that we have to look for other ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undocumented MEX functions do not have a corresponding prototype in `mex.h` header file, so you'll have to explicitly write one yourself. In this case it will be:

```
EXTERN_C mxArray *mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix(mwSize m, mwSize n, 
    mxClassID classid, mxComplexity flag);
```

The `EXTERN_C` macro expands to `extern "C"` if you are using C++, otherwise to `extern` in C, that way you get [correct linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041866/97160).

In C (not C++), any [undeclared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575186/97160) functions are assumed to be external functions that return an integer (at least that's the case with GCC compiler I think).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MathWorks has listened and made both [`mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreateuninitnumericmatrix.html) and [`mxCreateUninitNumericArray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreateuninitnumericarray.html) **documented in R2015a**.  They are declared in matrix.h as follows:

```
/*
 * Create an uninitialized numeric matrix.
 * The resulting array must be freed with mxDestroyArray.
 */
LIBMMWMATRIX_PUBLISHED_API_EXTERN_C mxArray *mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix(size_t m, 
    size_t n, mxClassID classid, mxComplexity flag);

/*
 * Create an uninitialized numeric array.
 * The resulting array must be freed with mxDestroyArray.
 */
LIBMMWMATRIX_PUBLISHED_API_EXTERN_C mxArray *mxCreateUninitNumericArray (size_t ndim, 
   size_t *dims, mxClassID classid, mxComplexity flag);
```

The macro `LIBMMWMATRIX_PUBLISHED_API_EXTERN_C` evaluates to `extern` or `extern C` (for MEX files), depending on whether the including source is C or C++.

The [official documentation for `mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreateuninitnumericmatrix.html) states:

> Call `mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix` to create a 2-D mxArray in which all data elements have the numeric data type specified by `classid`. Data elements are not initialized.
>
> `mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix` allocates dynamic memory to store the created `mxArray`. Call `mxDestroyArray` to deallocate the memory.

[Documentation for `mxCreateUninitNumericArray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreateuninitnumericarray.html) is similar.