# Unwrapping/unroll a truncated cone

Tags: matlab, math

I want to unwrape a pillar (truncated cone shaped) which has cone shape. How can I do it.

Lower radius=1.8506 m (red in pic)
Upper radius=1.6849 m (green in pic)

The coordinates of my pillar

center:
Bottom circle : xyz: 0,0,0 
Top circle : xyz: 0,0,24.6
Please see attached figure.

Cone apex: 0,0,275 (I just calculated)
angle (half)[image]:0.38
projection radius=1.84 ( WHAT should I give)[image]

The coordinates of cylinder, I  can get

```
r=sqrt(x^2+y^2)
theta=atan(y,x)
z=z
```

How can I project them on plane.

Comment: @mbschenkel: Think you intended to link this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526099/unrectified-image-from-unwrapping-a-truncated-cone

Comment: Could you point out the difference to your [second question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526099/unrectified-image-from-unwrapping-a-truncated-cone)? - Thanks for the correction @Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably many codes around on [fileexchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange) or highly optimized solutions on the web (for texture projection for instance), anyway here is my solution:

I assume pillar data is a matrix of size `[tcount x zcount]` where `tcount` is the number of scan positions along angular axis and `zcount` is the number of scan positions along height axis.

So here is the code:

```
%
% PURPOSE:
%
%   Project cone data to plane data
%
% INPUT:
%
%   thetaValues: Angular-scan values (in radians !!)
%   zValues: z-scan values (whathever unit)
%   coneData: Scanned data of size thetaCount-by-zCount
%   zminRadius: Radius at zmin position (same unit as zValues)
%   zmaxRadius: Radius at zmax position (same unit as zValues)
%   xvalues: Values to have along x-axis (by default biggestRadius * thetaValues centered around theta = 0)
%
% OUTPUT:
%
%   xvalues: Positions along x-axis (same unit as zValues)
%   zvalues: Positions along z-axis (same values/unit as input)
%   planeData: Plane data of size xcount-by-zcount 
%
function [xvalues, zValues, planeData] = Cone2Plane(thetaValues, zValues, coneData, zminRadius, zmaxRadius, xvalues)
%[
    % Default arguments
    if (nargin < 6), xvalues = []; end

    % Init
    zmin = min(zValues);
    zmax = max(zValues);    
    smallestRadius = min(zminRadius, zmaxRadius);
    biggestRadius = max(zminRadius, zmaxRadius);

    % Ensure thetaValues range in -pi;+pi;
    thetaValues = mod(thetaValues + pi, 2*pi) - pi;
    [thetaValues, si] = sort(thetaValues);
    coneData = coneData(si, :);

    % Intercept theorem (Thales)
    %
    %      A-------+-------\
    %     /|       |        \
    %    / |       |         \
    %   D--E-------+----------\
    %  /   |       |           \
    % B----C-------+------------\
    BC = biggestRadius - smallestRadius; 
    AE = zmax - zValues(:);
    AC = (zmax - zmin);
    DE = (BC * AE) / AC;
    radiuses = smallestRadius + DE;

    % Projection
    if (isempty(xvalues)), xvalues = biggestRadius * thetaValues; end
    xcount = length(xvalues);
    zcount = length(zValues);
    planeData = zeros(xcount, zcount);        
    for zi = 1:zcount,
        localX = radiuses(zi) * thetaValues;
        localValues = coneData(:, zi);
        planeData(:, zi) = interp1(localX, localValues, xvalues, 'linear', 0);
    end
%]
end
```

- I will not enter into details of [Thales theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) to compute `radiuses` for each z-position.
- I reorder angular positions to be in [-180°;+180°] so as to have symmetric x-positions (i.e. `xLocal = radiusLocal * angularPos`).
- The tricky part is to re-interpolate `xLocal` to some `xGlobal` positions (Which I assume to be `xLocal = biggestRadius * angularPos`, but you can of course provide your own values as an argument to `Cone2Plane` routine).

Here some test case:

```
function [] = TestCone2Plane()
%[
    % Scanning info
    zminRadius = 1.8506;
    zmaxRadius = 1.6849;
    zValues = linspace(0.0, 24.6, 100); 
    thetaValues = linspace(0, 359, 360) * pi / 180;

    % Build dummy cone data
    tcount = length(thetaValues);
    zcount = length(zValues);    
    coneData = rand(tcount, zcount);

    % Convert to plane data
    xvalues = []; % Means automatic x-positions
    [xvalues, zValues, planeData] = Cone2Plane(thetaValues, zValues, coneData, zminRadius, zmaxRadius, xvalues);

    % Display
    [X, Z] = ndgrid(xvalues, zValues);
    pcolor(X, Z, planeData);  
    shading flat;
%]
end
```

**Edit**

It is unclear what exact input data you have, but if pillar is a set of (x,y,z, intensity) points, you may reduce data set to coneData as follow:

```
thetas = atan2(y(:), x(:));
thetaValues = unique(thetas); tcount = length(thetaValues);
zValues = unique(z); zcount = length(zValues);    
coneData = zeros(tcount, zcount);
for ti = 1:tcount,
  logict = (thetas == thetaValues(ti));
  for zi = 1:zcount,
     logicz = (z == zValues(zi));
     coneData(ti, zi) = mean(intensity(logict & logicz));
  end
end
```

NB In practice, you may want to use some [unique with tolerance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1988634/684399) (+ `logic = abs(val-pos) < tol`) to further reduce data while accounting for noise in scan positions.

Comment: How can I get coneData from my theta and height. I have miilion of points. coneData = ndgrid(theta,height) would not work there. It is due to size of matrix.

Comment: @ vCitizenInsane. My data is Data=[X,Y,Z,Intensity]. How can I map my points with their original intensity,

Comment: @Shah It is unclear what exact input data you have; see my edits in the answer to see if it may suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

1. so you want get `(x,y,z)=f(u,v)` ?

   - `u=<0.0,1.0>` ... angle coordinate
   - `v=<0.0,1.0>` ... height coordinate let v=0.0 be bottom
   - you got 24 periods of `|sin|` waves along the perimeter
   - with amplitudes: `a0` at bottom and `a1` at the top
   - pillar has radius `r0` at bottom and `r1` at the top
   - pillar has height `h`
   - [image: pillar]
2. first basic cylinder

   ```
   x=r*cos(2.0*M_PI*u)
   y=r*sin(2.0*M_PI*u)
   z=h*v
   ```
3. now cone

   ```
   r=r0+(r1-r0)*v
   x=r*cos(2.0*M_PI*u)
   y=r*sin(2.0*M_PI*u)
   z=h*v
   ```

   - just linear interpolation of radius is added
4. now the `|sin|` waves

   ```
   r=r0+(r1-r0)*v
   a=a0+(a1-a0)*v
   r-=a*fabs(sin(2.0*M_PI*12.0*u))
   x=r*cos(2.0*M_PI*u)
   y=r*sin(2.0*M_PI*u)
   z=h*v
   ```

   - just linear interpolation of amplitude of `|sin|` wave is added
   - and then the `|sin|` wave is applied to radius

Now the `u,v` coordinates are the coordinates inside your plane (texture for example)

Comment: @ Spektre Thanx. What is M_PI.

Comment: @Shah `M_PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795` it is constant from C++ math.h ...

Comment: @Shah the waves could be anything I assumed |sin| but to make sure you should compare its shape to your pillar and use appropriate correction or function instead for example |sin^2(alpha)| ...or use alpha only on some range not the full circle ...if nothing is precise enough you can add bezier ...