# Unrectified image from unwrapping a truncated cone

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have 200 images taken round the truncated cone shaped object.
I have a classical question.

**Can I get unrectified images/orthoimage of a truncated cone shaped object?**

Option A: I have 3d point cloud of the object:

Option B: I have mesh of the object

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unwrapping/unroll a truncated cone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28494924/unwrapping-unroll-a-truncated-cone)

Comment: @ Daniel Why it is duplicate. I'm asking about image processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to project your image coordinates to a 2d plane. For a cone you could proceed like this:

For a simple approach you could ignore the fact that it's a truncated cone and treat it like a cylinder. For each point (alpha,r,z) on the cone calculate the angle alpha, distance r and height z. For a simple projection use alpha on the x and z on the z axis.

Your example image does not look like such a projection of a cylinder, rather it looks like the unwinding of a truncated cone. To implement this you must know the geometry of the full cone. If you know the geometry of each point, you need to calculate the distance from the cone tip S and the angle alpha. [image: Example]

Comment: Please, add support here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision/ Give votes to questions... We need Upvotes to go to the next level...