# Octave - find roots and count them

Tags: count, octave

I have the equation:

**sin(x) = exp(a)+4**

x = 1:.1:20

a = 0.02

I know i can use roots or fzero functions inside a loop to determine the roots.

How to use one or both of the above functions to find all the roots and them count them all in **sin(x) = exp(a)-4**

I wrote this code, it finds the zeros with fzero and marks them in plot. But how to modify to sin(x) = exp(a)-4 so **finds all roots and then counts the number of finded roots** and output the results.

```
x = 0:.1:20;
f = @(x) sin(x) + 4;
c = zeros(length(x),1);
for i=0:length(x)
    c = fzero(f,i);
    axis([0, 20, -2, 1])
    plot(x, f(x));
    title('Zeros de f(x) = sin(x) + 4');
    hold on
    plot(c, f(c),'-xr')
    hold on
end
```

**EDIT**

I used fzero inside a loop with the unique function to output, but it never outputs just the unique values. I outputs all duplicates. Anyone know why?

My new code:

```
h = @(x) cos(x);
g = @(x) exp(a*x)-1;

        f = @(x) h(x) - g(x);
        v = zeros(length(x),1);
        for i=0:length(x)
            v = fzero(f,i);
            [s] = unique(v)
        end
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can rearrange any equation problem to a root-finding problem by subtraction:

```
f = @(x) (sin(x) - (exp(a) + 4));
```

`roots` would operate on polynomials only. `fzero` is an iterative algorithm that *may* converge to one root close to the initial guess `i`.
Afterwards, you can use the `unique` function to extract the distinct solutions.

Comment: Many thanks... Please see my EDIT, as the duplicate function is not working as it should.

Comment: 1. Make sure that you stack all results of fzero in a vector. 2. Outside that loop, you really want to use a unique function that uses a tolerance, similar to answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1993859/2079934 Reason is that fzero is only an approximation and results differ at the order of the float precision, so you want to set that as a tolerance, for instance 10^-12