# What does "uniquetol" do, exactly?

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique, reverse-engineering

The [`uniquetol`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uniquetol.html) function, introduced in R2015a, computes "unique elements within tolerance". Specifically,

> `C = uniquetol(A,tol)` returns the unique elements in `A` using tolerance `tol`.

But the problem of finding unique elements with a given tolerance has **several solutions**. Which one is actually produced?

Let's see two examples:

1. Let `A = [3 5 7 9]` with absolute tolerance `2.5`. The output can be `[3 7]`,  or it can be `[5 9]`. Both solutions satisfy the requirement.
2. For `A = [1 3 5 7 9]` with absolute tolerance `2.5`, the output can be `[1 5 9]` or `[3 7]`. So even the *number* of elements in the output can vary.

See [this nice discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1988838/2586922) about the transitivity issue that lies at the heart of the problem.

So, how does `uniquetol` work? What output does it produce among the several existing solutions?

Comment: Why `reverse-engineering` tag?

Comment: @arrowd because he reverse-engineered the fucntion

Comment: @arrowd To be honest, I'm not totally sure it applies here. I think it does, as the description says _Reverse engineering is the process of discovering the technological principles of a human made [...] object or system through analysis of its [...] function and operation._

Answer (score 8):

To **simplify**, I consider the *one-output, two-input* version of `uniquetol`,

```
 C = uniquetol(A, tol);
```

where the first input is a `double` *vector* `A`. In particular, this implies that:

- The `'ByRows'` option of `uniquetol` is not used.
- The first input is a vector. If it were not, `uniquetol` would implicitly linearize to a column, as usual.
- The second input, which defines the tolerance, is interpreted [as follows](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uniquetol.html):

  > Two values, `u` and `v`, are within tolerance if `abs(u-v) <= tol*max(abs(A(:)))`

  That is, the specified tolerance is *relative* by default. The actual tolerance used in the comparisons is obtained by *scaling* by the maximum absolute value in `A`.

With these considerations, it seems that **the approach** that `uniquetol` uses is:

1. Sort `A`.
2. Pick the first entry of sorted `A`, and set this as *reference value* (this value will have to be updated later).
3. Write the reference value into the output `C`.
4. Skip subsequent entries of sorted `A` until one is found that is not within tolerance of the reference value. When that entry is found, take it as the new reference value and go back to step 3.

Of course, I'm not saying that this is what `uniquetol` *internally* does. But the *output* seems to be the same. So this is *functionally* equivalent to what `uniquetol` does.

The following **code** implements the approach described above (inefficient code, just to illustrate the point).

```
% Inputs A, tol
% Output C
tol_scaled = tol*max(abs(A(:))); % scale tolerance
C = []; % initiallize output. Will be extended
ref = NaN; % initiallize reference value to NaN. This will immediately cause
           % A(1) to become the new reference
for a = sort(A(:)).';
    if ~(a-ref <= tol_scaled)
        ref = a;
        C(end+1) = ref;
    end
end
```

To **verify** this, let's generate some random data and compare the output of `uniquetol` and of the above code:

```
clear
N = 1e3; % number of realizations
S = 1e5; % maximum input size
for n = 1:N;
    % Generate inputs:
    s = randi(S); % input size
    A = (2*rand(1,S)-1) / rand; % random input of length S; positive and 
                                % negative values; random scaling
    tol = .1*rand; % random tolerance (relative). Change value .1 as desired

    % Compute output:
    tol_scaled = tol*max(abs(A(:))); % scale tolerance
    C = []; % initiallize output. Will be extended
    ref = NaN; % initiallize reference value to NaN. This will immediately cause
               % A(1) to become the new reference 
    for a = sort(A(:)).';
        if ~(a-ref <= tol_scaled)
            ref = a;
            C(end+1) = ref;
        end
    end

    % Check if output is equal to that of uniquetol:
    assert(isequal(C, uniquetol(A, tol)))
end
```

In all my tests this has run without the assertion failing.

So, in **summary**, `uniquetol` seems to sort the input, pick its first entry, and *keep skipping entries for as long as it can*.

For the two examples in the question, the outputs are as follows. Note that the second input is specified as `2.5/9`, where `9` is the maximum of the first input, to achieve an absolute tolerance of `2.5`:

```
>> uniquetol([1 3 5 7 9], 2.5/9)
ans =
     1     5     9
>> uniquetol([3 5 7 9], 2.5/9)
ans =
     3     7
```

Comment: So, for the examples in the question, which is the output? (+1)

Comment: @AnderBiguri Good point, I'll include that. It basically picks the first value it finds, then skips values until it can skip no more. So: `uniquetol([3 5 7 9], 2.5/9)` gives `[3 7]`; `uniquetol([1 3 5 7 9], 2.5/9)` gives `[1 5 9]`.  Note the required `/9` so `2.5` is _absolute_ tolerance

Comment: Interesting! I would instead output the mean or the median of each set of equivalent values, which I think would be fairer somehow.

Comment: @CrisLuengo But would you still define _a set of equivalent values_ as is done by `uniquetol`? The seems to be a large degree of arbitrariness in the way it is done. (And thanks for the votes!)

Comment: Maybe an iterative process could lead to a more stable result?